# Unable to understand 理にかなっています meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases

`素の部分時系列ではなくて方向データを考えるのは、一般に時系列データにつきもののノイズを抑制すると言う観点で実用上理にかなっています`

In the above sentence I am unable to understand the `理にかなっています` phrase. Does anyone know what this means? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

理にかなう is a set phrase that means *is reasonable*, *to make sense*, etc.

理 is *reason*, and [かなう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/26257/5010) is *to match*, *to accord*. The kanji for かなう in this context is 適う, but it's usually written in hiragana.