# How to read 箕 (mi/mino）? Are these just different readings or is there a meaning difference?

Tags: meaning, readings

Why is 箕 transcribed as みの in this sentence while according to the dictionary (with the meaning of winnow; winnowing basket; winnowing fan​) it is read as み?

> 次の日、まだ夜が明けぬ暗い朝、女の子は起きると**箕**（みの）と箕かさを身にまとい出かけました。

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kanji that don't use their specified readings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38728/kanji-that-dont-use-their-specified-readings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, [箕【み】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AE%95) refers a winnowing basket made of bamboo. [蓑【みの】/簑【みの】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%93%91) refers to a straw raincoat. In this context, this みの obviously refers to the latter.

[image: *mi* and *mino*]

But I'm not sure if it's an outright typo. As proper nouns, a person called 箕谷【みのや】 and a station called [箕谷【みのたに】駅](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AE%95%E8%B0%B7%E9%A7%85) exist. So in [the old days when kanji usages were not standardized](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/26257/5010), 箕 might have been also used to refer to a raincoat.

Comment: I used to work in 箕面市 so I got interested and looked it up once. I don't remember where. But I did find みの as a reading of 箕 by itself. Ah, yeah: https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%AE%95 has this.