# Word Choice: 咽喉 vs. 喉

Tags: word-choice, wago-and-kango

http://jisho.org/word/%E5%92%BD%E5%96%89 
http://jisho.org/word/%E5%96%89

I came across 咽喉【のど】 while reading. Jisho doesn't have「のど」listed as a reading of 咽喉, but it *does* have it under 喉.

So now I'm wondering what the differences between 咽喉【のど】, 咽喉【いんこう】 and 喉【のど】 are, since both「のど」and「いんこう」are defined as "throat".

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4):

[咽喉]{いんこう} and [喉]{のど} are synonyms, but [咽喉]{いんこう} has a more limited usage, meaning either the throat (larynx + pharynx) or a vital passage.

[喉]{のど} also means throat, but it has a more wider, colloquial usage.

For example, you can say 「[喉]{のど}が[渇]{かわ}く」 (to be thirsty, lit. the throat becomes thirsty) but you can’t say 「[咽喉]{いんこう}が[渇]{かわ}く」

[喉]{のど} also means a (singing) voice, eg. のど自慢.

In this case, [咽喉]{のど} was probably used by the author to designate the actual body part while at the same time remaining more colloquial in tone.

Answer (score 4):

「のど」 is the original Japanese word for "throat".  It makes no difference if you write it in kana or kanji as we already had this word when Japanese was only a spoken language.  "Nodo" is the word that is intuitive to the native speakers.

「咽喉{いんこう}」 is the "big" Sino-loanword.  It sounds technical, formal, academic, etc. just like many Sino-loanwords do.  「咽喉」 is never a "household" word.

「のど」 is the word we use to talk about a throat 99.99% of the time in our daily life.

「咽喉」 is a medical term for us native speakers.  Unless you are a doctor, the only time you would utter this word would be when talking about 「耳鼻咽喉科{じびいんこうか}」 (an otolaryngologist's office, a.k.a. "an ear, nose and throat specialist").

[image]

Comment: Two comments from a non-native speaker, using [咽喉]{いんこう} has gotten me some mighty strange looks even when talking about a 耳鼻科. Apparently, there's a rather sketchy word with the same pronunciation (I've not bothered trying to learn exactly what that word means).

Comment: Second comment, most Americans (can't speak for the Brits, Aussies, Kiwis, etc.) say ENT or "Ear Nose Throat" Doctor but would know otolaryngologist.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the other answers for the difference between 咽喉【いんこう】 and 喉【のど】 (basically 咽喉 is a technical term, "laryngopharynx"). Mine is specifically about 咽喉【のど】.

The official reading of 喉 is のど, and that of 咽喉 is いんこう. のど is not listed as a reading of 咽喉, and it's not a mistake of jisho. None of the dictionaries I checked suggest 咽喉 can be read as のど, and my IME doesn't convert のど to 咽喉, either.

I think the usage of 咽喉【のど】 is more or less in the same vein as 未来【あす】, 希望【ゆめ】, 時間【とき】, etc., which is described in this question: [Why are some lyrics' words written in kanji whose usual reading is not how it is sung?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/198/5010) Sometimes novelists and lyricists want a complicated look of *kango* and a familiarity of *wago* at the same time. This is acceptable only in creative writing.

Or else, you may see a similar example in old novels, because [kanji readings were not very standardized](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/26257/5010) in those days anyway.